# Модель данных для динамических столбцов интерфейса

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, модель-данных, eav, реляционная-модель

Помогите, пожалуйста, спроектировать модель БД.
В документе закупки есть таблица c описанием закупаемых товаров. Требование к таблице с товарами( далее позиции):

1. У позиций есть столбцы по умолчанию: наименование позиции, количество, единица измерения.
2. Есть возможность добавить новый столбец, выбором из заранее преднастроенных, например, адрес поставки, дата поставки или цена товара. В этом случае, типы данных заранее известны(дата, значение из справочника адресов, цифры ).
3. Также, можно добавить сколько угодно новых столбцов с типом "Другое". В этом случае пользователь сам указывает наименование столбца. Поля в таких столбцах всегда текстового ввода.
4. Часть полей доступно для редактирования, часть недоступно, но показано в интерфейсе.
   БД на postgresql.
   Спроектировал для себя:
   ITEM - Информация с описанием позиций Есть  столбца по умолчанию.
   ITEM_ATTRIBUTES - Описание добавляемых столбцов с конкретным значением, которое вводит пользователь. Если ATTR_ID не пусто, то это значение из справочника атрибутов DICT_ATTRIBUTES.
   DICT_ATTRIBUTES - справочник заранее созданных столбцов(единица измерения, адрес, валюта и т.д.)
   Я не пойму, как связать DICT_ATTRIBUTES с таблицей конкретного справочника, чтобы на фронте прицепить этот справочник в выбор значений этого поля? Где отобразить какой тип данных несет каждый атрибут(текст, число, дата, булево и т.д.)? Ну и в целом может дадите совет как оптимальнее спроектировать динамические атрибуты для моих целей. Про тип данных  JSON в postgresql читал, но использовать его пока не планирую.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В общей куче у вас не получится это сделать. Нужно разделить схему на две части. В первой вы будите хранить метаданные описывающие отдельные сущности как таковые, а во второй экземпляры сущностей связанные со своими метаданными. Я опубликовал принципиальную схему данных решающих вашу задачу. Отследите одну цепочку: class -> class_prop -> class_prop_user_small_val-> objet_prop_user_small_val -> object https://github.com/firstDismay/pg-conception-builder/blob/master/Schemas/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D1%8E%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8B.pdf

Comment: Изучите паттерн EAV (Entity-Attribute-Value) и работу с ним.